# Can I remove a template from a category in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

We use a MediaWiki at our company to host internal documentation. I created a bunch of templates that is supposed to help with organisation and identification of all the pages within the wiki.

So, for example, I made a template called `wip` (work in progress) that adds an appropriate banner at the top of the page notifying the reader that the page is incomplete. This template also adds the page to an `unfinished` category so that we can easily display all pages that are still want of completion. This way, the page author can simply use the `transclude` function and add `{{wip}}` to the top of the page to have all the magic happen.

The problem is, if I generate a list of all the pages that are listed as being incomplete, the template page also shows up on this list, because the template page itself has the `[[Category:unfinished]]` directive.

Is there a way to make a transcluded template add its host to a category without itself belonging to that category?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Your question seems to be on topic here, so I edited out the introductory sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the `<includeonly>` tag. Anything in it will only be included when the template is transcluded, not on the template page itself. For your example, the template code would have this:

```
<includeonly>[[Category:unfinished]]</includeonly>
```